# Unable to disable rx-checksumming on virtual machine NIC

Tags: kvm

I am trying to build a VPN server on a virtual machine and the throughput is significantly low due to the fact that checksum offload is enabled on the NIC. I have run `ethtool -K enp1s0 rx off tx off` but rx does not work and I get 'Actual changes: rx-checksum: on [requested off] Could not change any device features'.' I ran `ethtool -k enp1s0` and it shows 'rx-checksumming: on [fixed]', indicating that it is fixed for some reason. Is there any way to disable Checksum offload by setting kernel parameters etc.? The paravirtualization device used is VirtIO. Thank you in advance.

I ran `ethtool -K enp1s0 rx off` but for some reason it is fixed and impossible to change the setting.
I want to disable rx-checksumming (Checksum Offload).